# How to make a sprite move up and down forever in swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a sprite move up and down forever, I have tried using an "if statement" which checks if the position is... than it will move up again. But it does not work.
I would really appreciate some help, thanks!
Here is the code.

```
var Ground = SKSpriteNode()
var Ground2 = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    Move()
}

func Move(){
    let action = SKAction.moveToY(self.frame.height / 2 - 360, duration: 5.0)
    Ground.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

    let action2 = SKAction.moveToY(self.frame.height / 2 + 140, duration: 5.0)
    Ground2.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action2))
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use action sequence for this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.purpleColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 10))

    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(frame))

    addChild(sprite)

    let moveUp = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 200, duration: 2)

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUp, moveUp.reversedAction()])

    sprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence), withKey:  "moving")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, just a question. What is the with key "moving"? Thanks

Comment: @DavidSundström It is a (unique) key which allows to access that particular action  later on in your code (and change it, stop it, remove it etc.)

Comment: Okey i get it, Thank you:)

Comment: The key is useful like when there is a game over or something else happen where you want the action to stop. You can access it anywhere in the code like this: removeActionForKey("moving").

Comment: The real benefits of using a key is in situations where you are running multiple actions on the same node, but you want to access a particular one.

Answer (score 1):

**Whirlwind's answer updated to Swift 5**

```
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.purple, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 10))

        sprite.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)

        addChild(sprite)

        let moveUp = SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 200, duration: 2)

        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUp, moveUp.reversed()])

        sprite.run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence), withKey:  "moving")
```